# Exporting: X, Y and turtle count in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to figure out the relationship my model produces with distance along the x axis, so I'm attempting to export a csv file that contains all combinations of X and Y coordinates, as well as the "density" which is defined as the

```
 ask patches [set density count turtles-here]
```

I'm tried simply using

```
output-print (ask patches [show density])

export-output "file.csv"
```

but either there's a flaw in my reasoning, or I'm coding it wrong (I do get an error but I'm missing the mistake somewhere). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
file-open "file.csv"
ask patches [
  file-print (word pxcor ", " pycor ", " density)
]
file-close
```

Comment: That's perfect. Follow up question though: say I also wanted to ask the turtles for some output. is there a way to have that output go to the same file but in a different sheet?